# Test on @@FETCH_STATUS deletes other variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, fetch

Im using **scroll cursor** on table with username and some other information on each row. I need to detect change of user so I know that I all information up to that point can be sent do one user, from this point to another...

It works fine but when I have just one user in table:

```
User1|something1|something1
User1|something2|something2
User1|something3|something3
```

I need to detect end, that I did like this:

```
declare @cr cursor scroll for select etc...
fetch first from cr into ...
while @@Fetch_Status=0 begin
... Collect data
/*Here is the problem*/
Fetch next into ...
/* some collected data from cursor here still exists (lets call them @data)*/
   if @@FETCH_STATUS=-1 begin
       -- Here are @Data = null
   end
end
```

I dont understand why that is. In another words, I need to know that this is the last line before everything is gone. Thank you

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand your question. why don't you move the `-- Here are @Data = null` after the end of your loop?

Comment: If the table was empty then I dont need to send anything. Also I tried that. After While loop are data gone

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You've 'collect data' for every row. Is the problem that you think data from your query is not being processed by the cursor or do you think that the cursor itself is not picking up data? BY the time you get to `if @@fetch_status=-1`, you've processed all data in the cursor

Comment: I add text into one variable with each row. At the end the variable is empty (its varchar(max)).

Comment: if the variable is empty, you maybe added a null. the end of the loop isn't the problem.

Comment: I agree with the loop. But still, I cannot find any problem with the string

Comment: "I add text into one variable with each row. At the end the variable is empty". Is this some logic in your SP? You should show it in your code. By "empty" do you mean NULL or blank string?

Comment: It seem that from certain row the variable is null. Still cannot find reason for it

Comment: Did you know that if you concatenate a string with NULL the result is NULL? Are you concatenating strings? It would help if you posted the actual code

Comment: I cant show code.But Im making some progress

Comment: Are you concatenating strings?

Comment: Ok now variable is not NULL but there is piece missing. How can I determine if it is too big for varchar(max)?

Comment: The last part is just cut out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While loop is fine. Concatenating varchar with null was to blame. Also my varchar is too big for MSSMS to show in Result or Messages windows.